# Inputs, drop-downs and buttons absolutely not working

Tags: html, button, input

Inputs, drop-downs and buttons are not working in my entire app. I just can't click on any of them, nothing's happening

I already tried to put a `<button type="submit">test</button>` in another file, not working as well, I can't click, it just wont let me.

I have added several values for the drop-downs, it didn't change anything.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXXK8.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SkKR.jpg

php form

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('price', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('TypeId', EntityType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'class' => Type::class
            ])
            ->add('ColorId', EntityType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'class' => Color::class
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class,
                [
                    'label' => 'Save',
                ]);
    }
```

php Controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $product = new Product();

        $form = $this->createForm(ProductForm::class, $product);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            $product = $form->getData();
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($product);
            $entityManager->flush();
            $this->addFlash(
                'notice',
                'Your product has been added !'
            );

            return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
        }
        return $this->render('product_add.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

twig

```
<div class="form-add">
        <h1>Enter the informations of your product in the form below</h1>

{{ form_start(form, {'action' : path('home'), 'method': 'PUSH'}) }}
{{ form_errors(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-add-errors'}}) }}
{{ form_row(form.name, {'attr': {'class': 'form-add-name'}}) }}
{{ form_row(form.price, {'attr': {'class': 'form-add-price'}}) }}
{{ form_row(form.TypeId, {'attr': {'class': 'form-add-type'}}) }}
{{ form_row(form.ColorId, {'attr': {'class': 'form-add-color'}}) }}
{{ form_row(form.save, {'attr': {'class': 'form-add-submit'}},{'label':'Submit me'}) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>
```

Comment: What does PHP have anything to do with this? Post your rendered HTML please

Comment: @j08691 The problem could be in the PHP (or twig) code used to render the HTML, couldn't it? I have no idea, not knowing either...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I can't see why unless the PHP is creating malformed HTML. The PHP creates the HTML and a button not being clickable doesn't seem to have to do with the PHP as much as the resultant HTML.

Comment: Well, I was thinking about the malformed HTML. No doubt we need the rendered HTML to confirm or not.

Comment: Just added a screenshot of the rendered html! I actually thought I did! Sorry

Comment: No, that's not the rendered HTML. We mean the actual HTML that is generated. Inspect the source with the browser's dev tools or view the source by right clicking and paste it here

Comment: that's what I did, there are 2 screens mate, click on both

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/eMOD1lQ